# i want to putHeader to my url when timeout equal 5s but it error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response has already been written"

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx3

I want to redirect to another url when timeout equal 5s.

Code that I have:

```
private void timeout(RoutingContext handler) {
    vertx.setPeriodic(5000, new Handler<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Long aLong) {
            System.out.println("Session expired : " + aLong);       
            handler.response().putHeader("location","/logout").setStatusCode(302).end();
        }
    });
}
```

Error that I get is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response has already been written"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a header when the response has already been written.
But you could check this condition and write:

```
public void handle(Long aLong) {
    if (!handler.response().headWritten()) 
        handler.response().putHeader("location","/logout").setStatusCode(302).end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple timer not a periodic one:

```
private void timeout(RoutingContext ctx) {
    long tid = ctx.vertx().setTimer(5000, t -> {
        ctx.response().putHeader("location","/logout").setStatusCode(302).end();
    });
    ctx.addBodyEndHandler(v -> ctx.vertx().cancelTimer(tid));
}
```

and don't forget to cancel the timer in case there wasn't timeout!